# Another carbon damage assessment?

Tags: frames, framebuilding

Mostly cosmetic? Chip is located on the bottom of the top tube. Did it go through a layer of carbon, or is that just paint/resin? Dime sized. This is an enduro mtb frame, so assuming it's built beefier than an ultralight road frame. I'm not super concerned but anyone with carbon experience would love your thoughts.. thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put some paint on it and you'd never know

Comment: Looks like it has just gone through the paint/primer and to the carbon only in the middle between the two "horns" in the first picture and there one seem to be some light scratches on the exposed carbon. We don't take any responsibility on internet advice but judging by the picture, this looks mostly cosmetic and far from any cracks or layers of carbon chipped off.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the provided pictures, for the most part only the paint chipped off, just in the marked segment, it went one layer deeper, probably just through the primer so that a little bit of carbon is exposed (approximately 2x5 mm)

The material below looks fine, I can't see any structural damage such as cracks, deep scratches or delamination, so I'd suggest: *Ride On*.

(Or get some paint to cover it up...)

[image]

Comment: I'd definitely put some paint on it - even clear nail polish would seal it.  There's no need to find out if getting it wet causes bad things to happen, no matter how unlikely.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ... and if it is just for the looks or to avoid more paint chipping off.